# ActiveMQ Artemis 2.18.0 killed from the critical analyzer

Tags: activemq-artemis

My ActiveMQ Artemis process is restarted from the critical analyzer with this message:

```
Component org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl is expired on path 3
```

```
AMQ224079: The process for the virtual machine will be killed, as component QueueImpl[name=01729809-eff0-11ed-bd3e-0a580a411ac1, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=test], temp=true]@57556b5a is not responsive
```

I don't understand why. Analyzing the CPU and the memory I don't find any problem.

I don't have other significant logs.

Comment: I m using the version 2.18.0

Answer (score 1):

There's been a number of fixes to critical analyzer since 2.18.0 was released almost 2 years ago now. You could very well be hitting one of these.

- [ARTEMIS-4084](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4084) - Rolling back massive amounts of messages might crash broker
- [ARTEMIS-3664](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3664) - Critical Analyzer should not kick in during Starting phase of the broker
- [ARTEMIS-3587](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-3587) - After upgrade: AMQ224107: The Critical Analyzer detected slow paths on the broker.

I recommend you upgrade to the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) which is 2.28.0 at this point.